# AdventureWorks2012:Identify the sales persons who have sales less than $100,000 since beginning of 2008. Show: Sales person login ID

Tags: sql-server-2012

AdventureWorks2012: Identify the sales persons who have sales less than  $100,000 since beginning of 2008.
Show: Sales person login ID.

I guess the tables will be

- `HumanResources.Employee`
- `Sales.SalesPerson`

Can someone plz help me. I have spent enough time

```
SELECT 
    E.LoginID 
FROM 
    HumanResources.Employee AS E 
JOIN 
    Sales.SalesPerson AS SP ON E.BusinessEntityID = SP.BusinessEntityID 
WHERE 
    E.BusinessEntityID IN (SELECT BusinessEntityID 
                           FROM Sales.SalesPerson 
                           WHERE SalesQuota < 100000);
```

Comment: SELECT E.LoginID FROM HumanResources.Employee AS E
JOIN Sales.SalesPerson AS SP ON E.BusinessEntityID = SP.BusinessEntityID
WHERE E.BusinessEntityID IN
   (SELECT BusinessEntityID  FROM Sales.SalesPerson WHERE SalesQuota < 100000);

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Sure.... Next time. I am using it first time. Stuck with these 4 queries from last 2 days, Researched good forums and joined this one  today.

Answer (score 0):

You're close - but you're not really looking at the **sales** that each sales person has had over the past years... The `SalesQuota` column that you're looking at in the `SalesPerson` table is usually a figure that is defined as a **goal** for the year - it's not an actual sum of all sales made.

I would try something like this:

```
-- determine the SUM of all sales, for all salespeople, since Jan 1, 2008
-- SUM the total of all sales (their TotalDue value) from the SalesOrderHeader table 
;WITH SalesPerPerson AS 
(
    SELECT 
        sp.BusinessEntityID, 
        TotalSales = SUM(soh.TotalDue)  -- SUM of all sales total amounts
    FROM 
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
    INNER JOIN 
        Sales.SalesPerson sp ON soh.SalesPersonID = sp.BusinessEntityID
    WHERE 
        soh.OrderDate >= '20080101'   -- on all sales since Jan 1, 2008
    GROUP BY
        sp.BusinessEntityID
)
-- from that CTE, select the sales people who have had less than 100'000$ in 
-- sales since Jan 1, 2008, and display those. Show LoginID and first and
-- last name (just for information purposes)
SELECT
    p.FirstName, p.LAstName, 
    e.LoginID,
    spp.*
FROM 
    SalesPerPerson spp
INNER JOIN 
    Person.Person p ON spp.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN 
    HumanResources.Employee e ON p.BusinessEntityID = e.BusinessEntityID
WHERE 
    TotalSales < 100000.0
```

So if you really only need the `LoginID`, you can leave out the JOIN to the `Person.Person` table and remove the `p.FirstName, p.LastName` columns from the output.

Comment: @user2223932: if this answer helped you solve you problem, you should [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.